# Adopted external sd card as internal storage - but storage space is not available

Tags: external-sd, 8.0-oreo, adoptable-storage

On my Xperia XZs with Android 8.0 I formatted the external SD card to be used as internal or adoptable storage. I had to use ADB to get this working. The system sees the storage, but I can't use it.

Total Commander only sees the internal memory, which is 20GB of 32GB internal memory. The 128GB external SD shows up as 256GB of which half is used.

**How can I get the SD card showing up as internal storage?**

[image: Internal Storage]

Comment: It is setup as internal device storage... if it wasn't then there would be a separate entry called Portable Storage and the SD card would be listed that way. Once it is adopted, apps should not see as uniquely separate from the rest of the device (you can no longer select SD card or internal separately). What size/brand of SD card do you have?

Comment: It's a 128GB sd card, brand shouldn't make a difference. This card has been used on this phone for the last year, so it works. So why doesn't Total Commander see that 128GB extra? It's only seeing 20GB.

Comment: If it is a 128GB card and is now being seen as 256GB (per the picture attached) then the card is likely failing. I can't explain why Total Commander sees things differently, I am not familiar with that application and only use Solid Explorer on my phone. SD cards used as adopted storage have a rather common issue of failing due to very high write usage, which is why many OEM's have disabled that feature in their devices. And although brand shouldn't make a difference, it can... it was a simple request. Remember that sd cards from less than reputable sellers are often counterfeit.

Comment: Samsung 128GB micro SD EVO Plus UHS-I 80MB/s

Comment: I stand by my earlier statement, if it is a 128GB card and is now being seen as a 256GB, something is wrong. Backup your data, convert it back to Portable Storage if possible, or zero the card and adopt it again. Card failure is very common with adopted storage

Comment: Same here with a 32GB SD Card just bought at a Samsung store. "87GB used of 128 GB" when the phone has 64GB + 32GB from SD is 96GB.

Comment: [How to free Internal Storage by moving data or using symlink / bind-mount with Adoptable Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214706/218526)

Comment: Thanks for the link - good to know and it might be useful with another phone. But that is Android 9, and that system has storage already merged. I have 8, and no merge.

Comment: "already merged" and "no merge" don't make sense. It's you, the user, who decides whether to use merged (Adoptable) storage or Portable. And technically it's not "merged". Both filesystems are mounted independently at different mount points.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, open SD card from screen displayed on screenshot in your question, than tap and hold recents button in nav bar or tap 3 dot menu if it's displayed, you will get various options one of them is migrate data tap on that and it should be fine.
Now because total commander see only one storage it is good, it is same case on my phone, and it works fine. Also adopted storage doesn't appear as internal storage it stays under same name and as external storage, but thing is that you can open app options in app manger in settings and choose to move to external storage in that case app will end up on adopted SD card.
When did you adopted SD card because it's already half full and as you said it didn't work as intended, when SD card is formatted as adoptable all data from SD card should be deleted.
Since it's showing 256 instead of 128 you should repeat process of adopting since something went wrong.

Comment: Uh.. I want to start using adopted storage *instead of* internal storage, and I *don't* want to migrate any data to the SD card - this defeats the whole purpose of what I am trying to do.  How do I get it to start using adopted storage *without* migrating everything and using up all the space on adopted storage???

Comment: And in my case, as soon as it was adopted, it claims that the "USB Drive" (it's an SD card on the USB interface) is "32GB of 32GB used (by system)" even though it's a 16GB card!